# Template Calls with Lambda Function - Error

Tags: c++, string, templates, vector, lambda

I'm trying to create a template which compares vectors of vectors of strings, ignoring the last 2 strings of the vectors of strings. The function template should ideally return 2 opposing sets of differences (diff and del) and 1 set intersection (red). However, this is the output:

diff:

del:

red: 
1001 01 100101

1101 11 110111

1111 10 111110

Program ended with exit code: 0

I am basing this off of: https://ideone.com/yJHN0L

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <assert.h>

template<class InputIt1, class InputIt2,
         class OutputIt1, class OutputIt2, class OutputIt3,
         class Compare>
OutputIt3 decompose_connections(InputIt1 first1, InputIt1 last1,
                               InputIt2 first2, InputIt2 last2,
                               OutputIt1 result1, OutputIt2 result2,
                               OutputIt3 result3, Compare comp)
{
    while (first1 != last1 && first2 != last2) {
        if (comp(*first1, *first2)) {
            *result1++ = *first1++;
        } else if (comp(*first2, *first1)) {
            *result2++ = *first2++;
        } else {
            *result3++ = *first1++;
            ++first2;
        }
    }
     std::copy(first1, last1, result1);
     std::copy(first2, last2, result2);
     return result3;
}

int main() {
// Simply as an example
    std::vector<std::string> A1, A2, A3, B1, B2, B3;
    std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> vecA, vecB, diff, del, red;

    std::string strA1_1 = "1101";
    std::string strA1_2 = "11";
    std::string strA1_3 = "110111";
    std::string strA2_1 = "1111";
    std::string strA2_2 = "10";
    std::string strA2_3 = "111110";
    std::string strA3_1 = "1001";
    std::string strA3_2 = "01";
    std::string strA3_3 = "100101";

    std::string strB1_1 = "1001";
    std::string strB1_2 = "11";
    std::string strB1_3 = "100111";
    std::string strB2_1 = "0111";
    std::string strB2_2 = "10";
    std::string strB2_3 = "011110";
    std::string strB3_1 = "1001";
    std::string strB3_2 = "01";
    std::string strB3_3 = "100101";

    A1.push_back(strA1_1); A1.push_back(strA1_2); A1.push_back(strA1_3);
    A2.push_back(strA2_1); A2.push_back(strA2_2); A2.push_back(strA2_3);
    A3.push_back(strA3_1); A3.push_back(strA3_2); A3.push_back(strA3_3);

    B1.push_back(strB1_1); B1.push_back(strB1_2); B1.push_back(strB1_3);
    B2.push_back(strB2_1); B2.push_back(strB2_2); B2.push_back(strB2_3);
    B3.push_back(strB3_1); B3.push_back(strB3_2); B3.push_back(strB3_3);

    vecA.push_back(A1); vecA.push_back(A2); vecA.push_back(A3);
    vecB.push_back(B1); vecB.push_back(B2); vecB.push_back(B3);
    // end example

    auto compare = [](std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>::const_reference lhs,
                  std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>::const_reference rhs)
    {
        assert(lhs.size() && rhs.size());
        return lexicographical_compare(lhs.begin(), prev(lhs.end(), 2),
                                       rhs.begin(), prev(rhs.end(), 2)
                                       );
    };

    std::sort(vecA.begin(), vecA.end());
    std::sort(vecB.begin(), vecB.end());

    decompose_connections(vecA.begin(), vecA.end(),
                          vecB.begin(), vecB.end(),
                          std::back_inserter(diff),
                          std::back_inserter(del),
                          std::back_inserter(red),
                          compare);

    std::cout << "diff: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < diff.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < diff[i].size(); j++) {
            std::cout << diff[i][j] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;


    std::cout << "del: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < del.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < del[i].size(); j++) {
            std::cout << del[i][j] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::cout << "red: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < red.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < red[i].size(); j++) {
            std::cout << red[i][j] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: My apologies. I've updated it with example vectors.

Comment: Can't reproduce with [clang](https://wandbox.org/permlink/XEaPZU3VBQZwdkoY). What's the compiler and version?

Comment: Cannot reproduce also with g++

Comment: I see, it was a problem with Xcode.

Comment: I was basing it off of this: https://ideone.com/yJHN0L

Any reason why the output is only this:

diff: 
del: 
red: 1001 01 100101 
1101 11 110111 
1111 10 111110